# Como mostrar os dados de um arquivo XML em um campo input com jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, nfe

Estou tendo desenvolver uma função que leia as informações que à nos campos de um arquivo do tipo .xml em PHP e tentando retornar essas informações nos campos de um formulário. Mais até o momento eu só consigo retornar os dados em forma de um objeto e a partir dai eu não estou conseguindo tratar de forma certa os dados retornados para preencher os campos do formulário. Espero ter sido claro e desde já agradeço ajuda de todos.
**HTML**

```
<form action="xmlNF-e/uploadXML.php" id="frmLoadXML" name="frmLoadXML" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!-- CAMPO DE BUSCA DO ARQUIVO XML -->
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Carregar Arquivo XML:</legend>
                    <div class="campo_carregamento">
                        <input type="file" name="carregarArquivoXML" id="carregarArquivoXML" /><span class="loading_file_xml"></span>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <form action="manutencaoConferenciaFaturamento.php" id="frmDados" name="frmDados" method="post" enctype="multpart/form-data">
```

Número

```
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                                        <label for="serie_pedido">Série</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="serie_pedido" id="serie_pedido" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
                                        <label for="chave_acesso">Chave de Acesso</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="chave_acesso" id="chave_acesso" value="" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" />
                                    </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
//Função responsável por carregar o arquivo xml do pc para uma pasta no projeto.
$("#carregarArquivoXML").on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url   : lerArquivoXML.php,
        type  : 'POST',
        cache : false,
        data  : new FormData($("#frmLoadXML")[0]),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        error : function(){
            alert('Erro ao tentar a ação!');
        },
        success : function( obj ){
            //var ex = dados.split('||');
            var dados = $.makeArray(obj);
            $.each(dados, function(chave, valor){
                alert(chave);
            });

            //alert(typeof dado);
            $("#carregarArquivoXML").val('');
            $(".loading_file_xml").fadeOut('slow');                
        },
        beforeSend : function(){
            $(".loading_file_xml").html("<img src='imagens/loading_xs.gif' alt='Enviando...' width='15' height='15' /> Enviando...").fadeIn('slow');        
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```

**lerArquivoXML.php**

```
function lerArquivoXML($nome=NULL){
if( $nome != NULL && file_exists("nota_compras/{$nome}")) {        
    // Converte o documento XML e o transforma em um objeto.
    $xml   = simplexml_load_file("nota_compras/{$nome}"); 
    $dados = array(        
        /* Dados da nota */            
        'nNF'      => $xml->NFe->infNFe->ide->nNF,       //Número da Nota.
        'serie'    => $xml->NFe->infNFe->ide->serie,     //Série da Nota.
        'id'       => $xml->NFe->infNFe->ide->id,        //Chave de Acesso.
    );

    return json_encode($dados);
} else {
    return json_encode('O arquivo não foi encontrado no diretorio!');
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para pegar somente os dados dentro do objeto voce pode usar o JSON

```
$.ajax({
        url   : "lerArquivoXML.php",
        type  : 'GET',
        cache : false,
        contentType  : "application/json",
        error : function(){
            alert('Erro ao tentar a ação!');
        },
        success : function(data){
           for(var i in data){
              console.log(data[i]);
           }         
        }
    });
```

No **type** use GET ao inves de POST, pois só irá receber dados, no **contentType** troque para application/json, pois voce esta retornando um *JSON* no seu *PHP*.

De uma lida na [documentacao](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)